# Сохранить входные данные в ячейку таблицы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Структура:

Вы нажимаете на ячейку, (Сделано)
Вы вводите что-то в поля ввода.(Сделано)
Я хочу сохранить измененные данные в ячейку хотелось бы через Mysql (PHP) . - Проблема

Буду рад получить ответ

Answer (score 1):

В своём варианте кода я буду использовать `GET`-запрос чтобы передать данные из формы.

**html**

```
<form action="/test.php" method=" GET " name="dfform">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Введите Ваше имя" />
    <input type="text" name="password" value="и пароль" />
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Сохранить" />
</form>
```

---

**php**

Библиотека для удобной работы с БД с защитой от SQL инъекций: https://github.com/digitalstars/DataBase (личная рекомендация, работал с ней очень долгое время).

1. Скачиваем библиотеку по ссылке.
2. Подключаем `autoload.php`.
3. Пример подключения к `Mysql`. (Больше примеров найдёте на GitHub)

```
use DigitalStars\DataBase\DB;

$db_type = 'mysql'; // Это может быть mysql, sybase или любой другой, в зависимости от вашей СуБД
$db_name = 'test'; // Имя БД
$login = 'root'; // Логин
$pass = 'pass'; // Пароль
$ip = 'localhost'; // Адрес

// С портом по умолчанию
$db = new DB("$db_type:host=$ip;dbname=$db_name", $login, $pass);
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

use DigitalStars\DataBase\DB;

$db_type = 'mysql'; // Это может быть mysql, sybase или любой другой, в зависимости от вашей СуБД
$db_name = 'test'; // Имя БД
$login = 'root'; // Логин
$pass = 'pass'; // Пароль
$ip = 'localhost'; // Адрес

// С портом по умолчанию
$db = new DB("$db_type:host=$ip;dbname=$db_name", $login, $pass

$filed1 = $_GET["name"];
$filed2 = $_GET["pasword"];

$db->insert('users', ['name' => $filed1, 'password' => $filed2]);

echo "Всё получилось!"

?>
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что так `$db = new DB("$db_type:host=$ip;dbname=$db_name", $login, $pass` у вас получится подключиться с базе данных?

Comment: @Quazimorda Прошу прощения, исправил

Comment: "В своём варианте кода я буду использовать GET-запрос" - а по стандарту надо POST

Comment: Библиотека ваша? Отличная работа. Но нарушать публичный контракт PDO всё же не стоило.

Comment: Библиотека не моя, моего друга. @Ипатьев